# Shopware6 First run wizard - how to verifiy domain locally

Tags: shopware

Last step of shopware6 first run wizard is 'Verify your domain'. 
I am running it at `http://localhost/shopware/sites/shopware1/public/`
What should i enter into 'shop domain' ?
I tried nearly everything but it is showing me error

```
Verification failed
The domain could not be verified


errors: [{code: "FRAMEWORK__STORE_ERROR", status: "500", title: "Verification failed",…}]
0: {code: "FRAMEWORK__STORE_ERROR", status: "500", title: "Verification failed",…}
code: "FRAMEWORK__STORE_ERROR"
detail: "The domain could not be verified"
meta: {documentationLink: "shop-domain-verification-failed"}
status: "500"
title: "Verification failed"
```

In documentation is written

```
It should be noted that the domain entered here must already be externally accessible and that the web server must refer to the public-Directory within the Shopware 6 installation.
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: For local shopware development you should use the docker or vagrant setup: https://www.sensus-media.de/blog/shopware-6-testumgebung-in-docker-installieren/ https://www.shopware.com/en/news/quickstart-shopware-6-for-windows-and-macos-user/

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip this step in the first run wizard, because you can't register local domains. There is no possibility to add this domain during the first run wizard. (But you won't need it to test and develop a shop at all)

Comment: there isnt option to skip this. only way i can skip is to update the core code to ignore first run wizard. i guess that isnt correct approach.

Comment: I don't get at what point you are facing this issue. In the first run wizard, there is clearly a button to skip the login to the shopware account.